# How do I apply a function to the groupby sub-groups that depends on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Take the following data frame and groupby object.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],[1, 4, 5],[2, 5, 6]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

print(df)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  1  4  5
2  2  5  6

dfGrouped = df.groupby(['a'])
```

How would I apply to the groupby object `dfGrouped`, multiplying each element of `b` and `c` together and then taking the sum. So for this example, `2*3 + 4*5 = 26` for the `1` group and `5*6 = 30` for the `0` group.

So my desired output for the groupby object is:

```
   a  f
0  1  26
2  2  30
```

Comment: you likely have to compute the multiplications, creating temporary columns, before summing via groupby. Something like this : ``df.assign(f=df.b.mul(df.c)).groupby("a", as_index=False).f.sum()``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],[1, 4, 5],[2, 5, 6]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df['f'] = df['c'] * df['b']
res = df.groupby('a', as_index=False)['f'].sum()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   a   f
0  1  26
1  2  30
```

Answer (score 1):

If need multiple all columns without `a` use [`DataFrame.prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) with aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df.drop('a', 1).prod(axis=1).groupby(df['a']).sum().reset_index(name='f')
print (df)
   a   f
0  1  26
1  2  30
```

Alternative with helper column:

```
df = df.assign(f = df.drop('a', 1).prod(axis=1)).groupby("a", as_index=False).f.sum()
```

If need multiple only some columns one idea is use @sammywemmy solution from comments:

```
df = df.assign(f = df.b.mul(df.c)).groupby("a", as_index=False).f.sum()
print (df)
   a   f
0  1  26
1  2  30
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
df=(df.b * df.c).groupby(df['a']).sum().reset_index(name="f")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a   f
0  1  26
1  2  30
```